# Successor of a countable ordinal is also countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I had this question when I was proving this theorem:

> Suppose $\omega_{1} = \left\{\alpha: \alpha \textrm{ is a countable ordinal}\right\}$. Then $\bigcup\omega_{1} = \omega_{1}$.

We may assume to know that $\omega_{1}$ is an uncountable ordinal (already proved). The following formula is easy to prove using transistivity of $\in$ for ordinals:

> $\bigcup\omega_{1} \subseteq \omega_{1}$,

and what is left is the inverse:

> $\omega_{1} \subseteq \bigcup\omega_{1}$.

That is, suppose $\beta \in \omega_{1}$, we need to show that $\beta \in \bigcup\omega_{1}$, which is equivalent to showing that $\omega_{1}$ is a limit ordinal. Thus, we need to show that $\beta^{+} \in \omega_{1}$. If $\beta$ is finite, the proof is very obvious. If $\beta$ is countably infinite, that is $\beta \approx \mathbb{N}$, we need to prove that $\beta \cup \left\{\beta\right\}$ is also countable, or $\beta \cup \left\{\beta\right\} \approx \mathbb{N}$. I guess it is obvious that $\beta \cup \left\{\beta\right\} \approx \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Then what is left is to show $\mathbb{N} \approx \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{\mathbb{N}\right\}$. I have come up with a function which may be able to establish this relation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f:\ &\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{\mathbb{N}\right\}\\
&\boldsymbol{0} \mapsto \mathbb{N}\\
&\boldsymbol{n}^{+} \mapsto \boldsymbol{n},\ \boldsymbol{0} < \boldsymbol{n}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I guess there is no problem arguing that this $f$ is a bijection. So $\beta^{+}$ is indeed countable. Thus $\omega_{1}$ is indeed a limit point, and $\omega_{1} \subseteq \bigcup \omega_{1}$. Is this process valid?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the procedure is fine. Just generalise it: if $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal we have a bijection $F: \Bbb N \to \alpha$.

Then define a bijection $F^+: \Bbb N \to \alpha^+= \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$ by

$$F^+(n) = \begin{cases} \alpha & n=0\\
 F(n-1) & n \ge 1 \end{cases}$$

This takes of the successor step. You also need to note that at limit stages, we take countable unions of countable ordinals and so these limits of ordinals below $\omega_1$ are still counatble ordinals too.